# Pivot Table Rows to be words of the initial cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table:

```
Search Terms  | Impressions  
metal gates   | 43,550  
gates         | 34,709  
sliding gates | 12,961
```

I'm trying to find out the number of impressions for each word:

```
Word    | Impressions  
gates   | 91,220  
metal   | 43,550  
sliding | 12,961
```

What's the fastest way of achieving this in Excel? In the meantime I've been able to solve this with a short Python script, but I'm trying to get better at Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your input table to Excel. Then ‘Text to Columns’ split the columns by “|”. SUMIF function did the actual summing by given word. Please have a look the screenshots.
Formulas not visible

[image]

Formulas visible 
[image]